# neo4j partial dump with cypher in java

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, vaadin

Yesterday i asked a question but it was unclear, so i created a new one with really better explanations to find the answer i need :).

So, in my Java Application, i need to do a neo4j copy System, here is an example:

```
       A      <--- this is a project 
      / \     <--- With relationships
     B   C    <--- and subnodes + Labels
    / \ / \   <--- with a depth unknown
   .........
```

I need to do a copy of this in my database, with another id, like this:

```
       A                 A1    
      / \               /  \     
     B   C             B1  C1  
    / \ / \           / \  / \  
   .........         ..........
```

In neo4j shell, i can simply use dump from A to n to return a cypher statement that i can copy and paste to neo4j web interface to create my copy.

But in fact, i'm in an application with java, so i need to find how to do the same thing, but with java (i'm using VAADIN framework + JDK7 + Neo4j 2.1.4).

I tried to use Neo4j-shell in java but never found how to get the reply from dump command (the cypher sentence) so i'm stuck now, and asking on stack overflow to get help :).

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Dump is a shell command, in theory you could instantiate and run it yourself.

It uses the SubgraphExporter from the Cypher module, Neo4j is OSS you can find it on [GitHub](http://github.com/neo4j/neo4j)

In general it should be easier for you to run a cypher query against the database yourself and then with the results recreate the data you're interested in.

Something like this should help you:

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/developer-resources/blob/gh-pages/examples/java/jdbc/src/main/java/example/jdbc/movies/MovieService.java#L58

Comment: Problem is i don't know how to get labels, relationships and properties from all of the subnodes of my node n, i need to copy the project with all of his labels, relationships and properties

Comment: Can you please give me an example on how to get the project with all of his labels, relationships and properties? the only way i found is dump shell command, but if a cypher solution exists, it can be great too

Comment: your link seems broken btw