# How to return all properties of a node with their name and their value using Cypher

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I saw here : [How can I return all properties for a node using Cypher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735005/how-can-i-return-all-properties-for-a-node-using-cypher) that somebody already asked this question, but 1 year ago.

So i need to ask it now : is there a way, today, to return all properties of a node using cypher? i need to do it for a translation system where previous developpers have created it as 1 node per language, with contains all of the properties with their name in the desired language. I need to get it for a Java application.

Example:

```
node FR contains: "Salut_01" : "Bonjour"
node UK contains: "Salut_01" : "Hello"
```

etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i finally did:

```
private IndexedContainer getTradParameters(int id){
        IndexedContainer container = new IndexedContainer();
        container.addContainerProperty("name", String.class, null);
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://10.0.0.1:7474/db/data/node/"+id+"/").get();
            Elements properties = doc.select("th");
            for(int index = 0; index < properties.size(); index++){
                String parameter = properties.get(index).text();
                Item item = container.addItem(index);
                item.getItemProperty("name").setValue(parameter);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return container;
    }
```

Where the id parameter is returned by this:

```
match (t:Translation) return id(t)
```

I call getTradParameters() with every iterator of my request and then i have a container with the name of all of the parameters of my node.

The Last part is calling this function :

```
private String getTradRequest(String pays){
        String request = "match (n:Translation{trad_country:\""+pays+"\"}) return id(n) as id";
        QueryResult <Map<String,Object>>result = engine.query(request, Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
        Iterator<Map<String, Object>> iterator=result.iterator();
        Map<String,Object> row = iterator.next();
        int id = Integer.valueOf(row.get("id").toString());
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://10.0.0.1:7474/db/data/node/"+id+"/").get();
            Elements properties = doc.select("th");
            for(int index = 0; index < properties.size(); index++){
                String parameter = properties.get(index).text();
                request = request + ",n."+parameter;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return request;
    }
```

To create my big Cypher request to get all of the properties i need on my node, and then i just need to get the answers and store them in a container, to display it in a table using vaadin.

Answer (score 0):

If you return the node directly from cypher via the http endpoints it will return a map with all property-names and property-values.

```
 MATCH (n) return n
```

In Java you'd just go over `n.getPropertyKeys()`.

For your regexp question you should split up your question into two.

Comment: Your answer seems to be good but i don't know how to use the http endpoint, i have the same problem with your answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175969/neo4j-partial-dump-with-cypher-in-java
I found a solution in java, will post it when i'll have done all of the code