# How to get attributes of a Neo4j node

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I am making a connection to the `neo4j` in `Nodejs` to get the attribute of `ServiceConsumer` node. But not sure, how to do it. here is my code which connect to the neo4j. Suppose ServiceConsumer has some attributes like `city`, `state`, `name`, `userId` and I have to retrieve the name of ServiceConsumer. I am getting the `userId` from the frontend and on the basis of this `userId` querying the neo4j database to get the node information.How would i get the name of ServiceConsumer? Any help ll be appreciated.

```
var user = this.userId;
    var request = require("request");
    var host = 'localhost';
        port = 7474;
    var httpurlforconnection ='http://' + host + ':' + port + '/db/data/transaction/commit';


    /*Let’s define a function which fires the cypher query.*/

    function runCypherQuery(query, user, callback) {
      request.post({
          uri: httpUrlForTransaction,
          json: {statements: [{statement: query, parameters: user}]}
        },
        function (err, res, body) {
          callback(err, body);
        })
    }

    // Let’s fire some queries below 

    runCypherQuery(
      'MATCH (n:ServiceConsumer {userId : {} }) RETURN n', {
        userId: 'user',
      }, function (err, resp) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(resp);
        }
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [How to return all properties of a node with their name and their value using Cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274135/how-to-return-all-properties-of-a-node-with-their-name-and-their-value-using-cyp)

You can do the same thing using nodejs, simple POST can return the whole node to you and then simply cast it to an object using JSON.

By the way, your code is working fine, you can simply take the "resp" object which should contain the result JSON.

Comment: thanks for your answer, little busy...i'll try it later.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious thing that I see is that you're not specifying the userId parameter.  You Cypher should look something like this:

```
MATCH (n:ServiceConsumer {userId: {user_id}}) RETURN n
```

Does that help?

Comment: actually, i am passing the userId parameter at runtime, i have stored it in variable "user". userId won't be hard-coded.

Comment: Yeah, I see that you're passing the `userId` parameter in, but you weren't specifying where it went in the query string.  Just putting empty brackets like `{}` doesn't do anything, I don't think